# Angular + SCSS !default not working

Tags: angular, sass

Scss has the !default feature, to easily allow a client to override a value.

However, if I use it in Angular it doesn't work, I think due to Angular's encapsulation. Example:

In styles.scss I have:

```
$hello-background: red;
@import 'app/variables';
```

and in app/variables:

```
$hello-background: yellow !default;
```

and in hello.component.scss:

```
@import '../variables';
:host {
  display: block;
  background: $hello-background;
}
```

Then the background is yellow, even though I tried setting it to red first. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: have you added `styles.scss` into `.angular-cli.json` ?

Comment: yes i have added it

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution for this problem. I am facing the same problem. I have some customer styles that i want to load dynamically and override the default styles. So i can't load the customer specifc styles inside the component

Answer (score 2):

It's because the variables you set/define in `styles.scss` are not imported in your component (which does not know about `styles.scss`), so the default value from `app/variables` is used. If you want to override the variables both in global `styles.scss` and in components, you can use something like this:

**app/variables.scss**

```
$hello-background: yellow !default;
```

**app/override.scss**

```
$hello-background: red;
```

**styles.scss**

```
@import 'app/override';
@import 'app/variables';
```

**hello.component.scss:**

```
@import '../overrides';
@import '../variables';
:host {
  display: block;
  background: $hello-background;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the stylesheet you think is being applied is actually being applied. If this is a component in a website of many components put your over-ride value into you app-level .scss file `app.component.scss` and see if it is applied then.